# Splitting delimited table into rows

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, delimiter

I've got some data very similar to this:

```
ID  STATUS                  EMPL
1   Created;Solved;Closed   John;Terry;Martin
```

Of course the number of values in each row can range from 1 to n. I found some advices on this for 1 column only (using Connect by with regexp_substr)

Is there any way (SQL or PL/SQL wise) to get to desired output:

```
ID  STATUS   EMPL
1   Created  John
1   Solved   Terry
1   Closed   Martin
```

Thanks

Comment: Write a function or SP. Have a cursor in it and loop through with each row. On each row, split your data with (;) as shown in question. Now have an temp table and keep adding.

Comment: This would be _much_ easier to handle in your app layer, e.g. Java.  Databases aren't the best places to scrub your data.

Comment: First of all normalize or at least use collection type. Using CSV is very poor idea.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I realize this is not ideal, but this is how it is done in the company I work for - not much I can do...

Comment: I agree with @TimBiegeleisen, having in front end code would be good. If you have any policy which is holding you back then go with SQL option.

Comment: You can use the regexp_substr on multiple columns with the connect by solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure of the performance on big tables but this select should work

```
select st.id, st.status, em.empl from (
    select distinct id, level as lvl, regexp_substr(status,'[^;]+',1,level) as status 
    from to_split connect by regexp_substr(status,'[^;]+',1,level) is not null
) st
join (
    select distinct id, level as lvl, regexp_substr(empl,'[^;]+',1,level) as empl 
    from to_split connect by regexp_substr(empl,'[^;]+',1,level) is not null
) em
on st.id = em.id and st.lvl = em.lvl
order by id;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
with d (id, status, empl) as 
(
  select 1   ,'Created;Solved;Closed',                 'John;Terry;Martin'          from dual union all
  select 2   ,'Created2;Reviewed2;Solved2;Closed2',    'John2;Bell2;Terry2;Martin2' from dual
) 
,cte(id, status, s, e, empl, s1, e1, rn) as 
(
  select 
    id, status, 1, case when instr(status, ';') > 0 then instr(status, ';') else length(status)+1 end, 
          empl, 1, case when instr(empl, ';')   > 0 then instr(empl, ';')   else length(empl)+1 end, 0  
  from d
  union all 
  select 
    id, status,  e+1, case when instr(status, ';' , e+1) > 0 then instr(status, ';', e+1) else length(status)+1 end,  
          empl, e1+1, case when instr(empl, ';'  , e1+1) > 0 then instr(empl, ';',  e1+1) else length(empl)+1 end, rn+1 
  from cte where e <= length(status)
  -- assumption: equal number of delimiters (;) in status and empl column values
)
select id, substr(status, s, e - s) status, substr(empl, s1, e1 - s1) empl  from cte
order by id,rn
;

        ID STATUS                             EMPL                     
---------- ---------------------------------- --------------------------
         1 Created                            John                       
         1 Solved                             Terry                      
         1 Closed                             Martin                     
         2 Created2                           John2                      
         2 Reviewed2                          Bell2                      
         2 Solved2                            Terry2                     
         2 Closed2                            Martin2
```